# What is the advantage of RTSP over plain HTTP for static files?

Tags: http, language-agnostic, video-streaming, rtsp

Is there any advantage of using RTSP for serving static (not live stream) TS videos?

HTTP looks like better for this purpose and triggers less bugs in client software. Seeking works better, fast-forward playback works smoother. It also does not require any indexes.

Are there any pitfalls when migrating from RTSP to plain HTTP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usage of HTTP for media streaming, while sponsored by Apple iOS products, is probably not as standard as RTSP. There are many HTTP streaming implementations, whose issues are mainly:

- inability to PAUSE;
- byte-range seeks.

Other than this, HTTP is better for many reasons.

See [this article](http://www.remlab.net/op/vod.shtml).

Comment: What does mean "inability to PAUSE"? Better to say "No explicit PAUSE verb so need to work around by stalling TCP session or reconnecting".

Answer (score 1):

HTTP "streaming" servers will (in most cases) use TCP as their network transport, RTSP servers *usually* offer RTP over UDP which is more suited to multimedia streaming where some errors/packet loss can be tolerated with the benefit of lower latency and less network overheads.

Answer (score 0):

Also, as RTSP it is over UDP, it can be used inside LAN with multicast/broadcast. This is quite useful for TV streams as you will use less bandwidth.

Comment: Quotation from the question: "serving static (not live stream) TS videos".